# Add a key to std::map without a value

Tags: c++

Suppose i defined a global map -

```
map<int,list<char>> cMap;
```

Is there a way (**without using the `boost` library**) that i can add integer keys, and later on in the program add values to the lists that correspond to them?

```
map<int,list<char>> cmap;

int main()
{

// Add only a value this way?
cmap[2];

// and then -
cmap[2].push_back('A');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you have already? Looks fine to me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**You're already doing it.**

When you write `cmap[2]`, and that element doesn't exist, it is created and default-constructed.

So, `cmap[2]` will be an empty list. Then you can `.push_back` to it whenever you like.

Since this process is also triggered by the `cmap[2]` in `cmap[2].push_back(..)`, you don't actually need the initial "empty" initialisation unless there's some requirement in your project for the key to exist in the map from the start (in which case, fair enough).

If you don't want an empty list to be the value but for there to be no value, I think that this is silly but you have some options:

- Don't add the key, either
  *(let the lack of the key **mean** lack of the value)*;
- Store `std::unique_ptr<std::list<char>>` and start off with `nullptr`
  *(yuk; dynamic allocation for no good reason; no thanks!)*;
- Store `std::optional<std::list<char>>` and start off with `cmap[2] = std::none`
  *(when `Boost.Optional` makes it into C++, which is happening but slowly)*.

And… that's it.

Comment: Thank you. but i don't understand what will happen if i'll add another `cmap[2];`  right after `cmap[2].push_back('A');` ? what will happen to the list?

Comment: @AlexGoft Nothing will happen to it. From this answer: "When you write `cmap[2]`, **and that element doesn't exist,** it is created and default-constructed." When you write `cmap[2]`, and that element does exist, you simply obtain the value. Since you don't do anything with it, all the items in the list will remain in the list.

Comment: @AlexGoft `'A'` will get pushed into the list

Comment: @AlexGoft: You're over-thinking it.

Comment: "...you simply obtain the value. Since you don't do anything with it, all the items in the list will remain in the list." is exactly what i wanted to understand . Thanks again, kind sir